# A subgroup of direct product of countable copies $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

This is an example from Rotman's Homological Algebra (p.122, old edition).

Let $G$ be the direct product of countable copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ (say, group of sequences of integers).

Fix a prime $p$.

Let $S$ be the subgroup consisting of all those sequences in $G$ such that for every $k\ge 1$, all except finitely many entries of sequence are divisible by $p^k$.

It is then shown in book that this subgroup is not free (by some arguments).

It was shown that this subgroup is uncountable; I didn't understand this fact about cardinality. Any hint for this?

Comment: Normally you have to construct something like Cantor's diagonalization argument for such things

Comment: I don't know which argument was given in your book. I don't have it here. But you can inject any element of $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ into $G$ by multiplying it, componentwise, by $(1,p,p^2,p^3,...)$. Therefore, $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: More precisely this provides an injective group homomorphism from $\mathbf{Z}^{\mathbf{N}}$ into this group. Hence it has continuum cardinality, and this also implies that it's not free abelian, using that $\mathbf{Z}^{\mathbf{N}}$ is not free abelian and that being free abelian passes to subgroups.